# Is it possible to read signal strength of USB mouse to detect its proximity in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, signal, wireless-mouse

Similar to the idea of detecting proximity via Bluetooth signal strength, I was wondering if it is possible to read such information for USB wireless mousein a linux system.

Comment: Does a wireless mouse dongle even supply signal strength information to the host?  Any information you've found by research would make a good addition to your question, so others won't be reproducing work trying to figure out what you've already found, if anything.

Comment: To be honest I got the idea when I was playing with xinput query-state which prints something like "ValuatorClass Mode=Relative Proximity=In" with some valuator values. But couldn't find anything upon that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe this would possible.  It appears to me that most of the USB peripherals use USB as connection to a PC, but the radio signals appear to be proprietary to the device manufacturer.  It *may* be possible through the [wireless USB standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_USB), but the adoption rate has been abysmal.  Unless the manufacturer provides a hook into its driver/application, I dont see how you could detect the signal.  I dont believe I have seen any wireless USB devices provide signal information.

On top of that, wireless signals in general are so finicky, that it might be hard to read.  Im sure we have all wondered why out WiFi connection dies in certain spots for no apparent reason.